# Is there a way to preform calculations in a cypher query?

Tags: neo4j, cypher

Is there a way to order by a calculated value based on relationships, rather than a label? For reference, I have a database containing users and skills.  If applicable, each user node has a relationship with a skill node.  Each skill has a specific value tied to it that represents how important that skill is.  If a user wants to find similar users, what I am currently doing matching all distinct users with similar skills.  What I want to do is sum up the values contained in each skill node that I'm looking for for a particular user, and sort from greatest to least.  For example, if I'm looking for people that like to swim, run, and bike if Billy likes to swim and run I would take the values stored in each similar skill and sum them to use as the property to sort by.  Is this possible in purely cypher, or would I have to return the list of results and then calculate/sort outside of cypher?  If anyone has any other advice on how to better structure the database that would also be helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is pretty easy in Cypher and is for sure documented in a lot of places.

Here a couple of examples :

Finding users like Bob, based on similar skills, order by sum of skill importance on the skill node :

```
MATCH (n:User {name: 'Bob'})-[:HAS_SKILL]->(skill)<-[:HAS_SKILL]-(otherUser)
RETURN otherUser.name AS name, sum(skill.score) AS score
ORDER BY score DESC
```

In some graph models, each user can be associated a score to each skill, in which case the score would be on the relationship between the user and the skill, you can then sum up those as well :

```
MATCH (n:User {name: 'Bob'})-[r1:HAS_SKILL]->(skill)<-[r2:HAS_SKILL]-(otherUser)
RETURN otherUser.name AS name, sum(r1.score + r2.score) AS score
ORDER BY score DESC
```